# Use Keycloak with pgbouncer

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, keycloak, pgbouncer

I have a postgresql with pgbouncer. 
Key cloak is deployed to kubernetes, the image is: `jboss/keycloak`
I want to be able to control the number of connections keycloak is using.

I see two options:

1. modify keycloak to connect to pgbouncer instead of directly connecting to postgresql
2. modify keycloak's max-pool-size

if I do the first, I'll get the following error:

```
06:06:48,434 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ARJUNA016039: onePhaseCommit on < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff0af40125:-3771dfc6:5ea524d4:13, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff0af40125:-3771dfc6:5ea524d4:1b, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS > (LocalXAResourceImpl@8359d05[connectionListener=68462788 connectionManager=21312d94 warned=false currentXid=null productName=PostgreSQL productVersion=11.7 jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS]) failed with exception XAException.XA_RBROLLBACK: org.jboss.jca.core.spi.transaction.local.LocalXAException: IJ001156: Could not commit local transaction
```

For the second, I see no environment variable to control it, so I'll need to build and maintain the image myself.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the bouncer working with RedHat SSO/Keycloak after quite a few issues. I haven't been able to resolve using the bouncer on SSO deployment/startup, as I think the bouncer is unable to perform those local transactions, but if you check the database you'll likely see a number of tables were successfully created. Instead, during initial deployment, have SSO connect directly to your database, then in a post config job update the data-source connection to use the bouncer service name with the following command (to be run inside of keycloak):

```
/opt/eap/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=sso_postgresqlObjectStorePool/:write-attribute(name="connection-url", value="jdbc:postgresql://sso-pgbouncer:5432/userdb")'
```

Make sure to update your data-source name to match the one generated by keycloak (unless you specified it in the standalone.xml). Alternatively, there is a batch list of jboss-eap commands that get called on startup in `/opt/eap/bin/keycloak-launch.cli` that you may be able to update and append the above command to the end of that file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm running Keycloak in kubernetes, let's see if I can follow this without making the deployments too complex (like, I prefer not to compile and maintain my own image)